# PHP: Create key=>value pair from strings with colons

Tags: php, arrays

I have following problem: I make a cURL request and get a response like this (no json):

```
100
123456
Foo: Bar
Foo1: Bar1
Foo2: Bar2
```

To be able to work with that data, I create an array:

```
$result = preg_split("/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/", $result);
```

Now I have an array with these items:

```
array(
    "100",
    "123456",
    "Foo: Bar",
    "Foo1: Bar1",
    "Foo2: Bar2"
)
```

My question is: Is there a nice way to create an array with key => value pairs, so the strings before the colons are the keys and the ones after the colons the values? The first two items never have colons, so I need to add a key to them separately and the string before the colons is never the same, so it isn't possible that there is the same key multiple times. Also, there's either just one or no colon.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give an example of what the result would look like?  What should happen if a key is defined multiple times?  What if the strings have zero or multiple colons?

Comment: Some of the items in your example have no colon.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the strings before the colons never are the same, and there is always just one or no colon.

Comment: Information related to the question should be added to the question itself. Don't put in comments. Edit the question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code assumes that no keys are duplicates. If there are, the later one will overwrite the earlier. Entries that have no colon will use keys 0,1,2 etc.

```
$data = array(
    "100",
    "123456",
    "Foo: Bar",
    "Foo1: Bar1",
    "Foo2: Bar2"
);

$o = array_reduce($data, function($carry, $m){
    //echo $m . "\n";
    $e = explode(':', $m, 2);

    if ( count($e) == 1 ) {
        $carry[] = trim($e[0]);
    } else {
        $carry[$e[0]] = trim($e[1]);
    }
    return $carry;
}, []);

print_r($o);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 123456
    [Foo] =>  Bar
    [Foo1] =>  Bar1
    [Foo2] =>  Bar2
)
```